# When submitting form for a new object - going to another route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a question regarding the submissions of forms in rails.
I have a form:

```
 <%= form_for Event.new, multipart: true, class: 'form' do |f| %>
```

In the controller:

```
def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)

    if @event.save

      redirect_to dashboard_event_path @event
    else
      flash[:error] ||= 'Please fix the event\'s details'
      render :new
    end
```

Working on a new Event object. (i.e. /events/new)
However, when I'm posting that form, and there are validation errors, it will render that form again, but the url will be /events/. is that normal? I know that the routes for new is /new and create is POST to /events, but how do I keep the browser in the /new url?

Help?

Thanks

Comment: it must be `/events/create` when there are validations errors

Comment: @Nithin no, /events is normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly normal, nothing to be done here. Making the URL stay the same would be changing how Rails works internally - it's really not worth doing that.

Comment: so what you are saying, is that if there is form errors, the browser will move to /events/ and if the user refreshes the page, it will get something else. and this is normal?

Comment: If the user refreshes the page of a form post, they will get a big error saying 'are you sure you want to refresh a form post?' and if they say yes, they will still get the form with validation errors.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal.  You are responding from the events method in the controller.  Just because you got the html from a file with another name doesn't mean the url will change. If you want the url to change, the easiest thing to do would be to redirect to the new page instead of rendering it

Comment: No, I mean that the URL is changing, but I dont want it to! redirect is something else. I am talking about rendering...

Comment: Could you post all the code for your controller?  You should start in `new` and the submitted form should be going to `create`, meaning that the code you posted is from `create`.  I was talking about redirecting back to `new`.

Comment: I edited the question. I dont want to redirect back to new. because then the flash msgs won't appear! neither do validations